# How to change the value "is_required" in the table eav_attribute in the entity_type_id "2" and with the attribute_code "lastname" programmatically

Tags: magento2, php, database, attributes

Good day people,

I have been trying to change the value `is_required` in the table `eav_attribute` in the `entity_type_id` `2` and with the `attribute_code` `lastname` in Magento 2
but without success,
this is what I have so far:

```php
<?php

namespace Orienteed\AdminUserForms\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;



class UpgradeData implements Setup\UpgradeDataInterface
{
 

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $_eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * __construct
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(
        Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Setup\ModuleContextInterface $moduleContext
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($moduleContext->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
            $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
                $eavSetup->updateEntityType("25", "is_required", "0");
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use Data Patch for this like:

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Setup/Patch/Data/UpdateCustomerAddressLastname.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class UpdateCustomerAddressLastname implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    protected ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup;
    protected EavSetupFactory          $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function apply(): void
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();

        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'lastname', 'is_required', '0');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();

    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function revert(): void
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();

        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'lastname', 'is_required', '1');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }
}
```

P.S. I don't recommend to use hard-coded id in upgrades

Comment: Thanks for the response sir Victor Tihonchuk, it worked perfectly,
The things is I am kind of a newbie in magento I haven't find a good resource to properly learned it,
If you don't matter that I ask, what would you recommend in this case?
and, were can I find good resources to learn magento properly?
can you recommend me one please?